# Is there a function which equals the following when differentiated

Tags: calculus

Is there a function $F(x)$ with $F'(x)= \sin(\cos(\sin(\cos(\sin(x)))))$?
If it's true, I must show this function, otherwise provide an argument why this doesn't exist.

Will be very grateful if anyone can help me with this as I have been stuck on it a long time.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: $F(x) = \int_0^x F'(t)\,dt$.

Comment: Has anyone have the correct answer ??

Comment: My answer may not be the one you are looking for, but it *is* correct.

Comment: Looks like a homework question to me. I wonder just how long have you been stuck on this one considering I released it today as homework.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. As suggested by rogerl, the function you are looking for is
$$F(X) = \int_0^x \sin(\cos(\sin(\cos(\sin(t))))) dt. $$

The integral is well defined for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$, since the integrand is bounded. Whether or not it has a *closed form* is an entirely different topic (and I would be surprised if it had).

Comment: Please refrain from giving complete answers to questions posted showing minimal effort.

Comment: Ok, I'll keep that in mind. Is there a reason?

Comment: The reason is to avoid answering somebody else’s homework for them. That’s why they need to show more than minimal effort.